# I need to remove some words into a cell of a dataframe with a condition until a ","

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one data set in the column "Tags" I would like to remove in each cell from the world "importacion" to the "," and in some cases, it is just alone without the ",":

```
"importacion-2022-04-20-10:35:20, curioso, new user,lead_player,female,view_snapshot_cinnabon,like_cinnabon,view_legals_cinnabon,view_snapshot_moneypool,view_snapshot_la borra del cafÃ©,view_snapshot_galt energy,like_la borra del cafÃ©,view_snapshot_mccarthy's irish pub,like_mccarthy's irish pub,view_snapshot_la cervecerÃ\xada de barrio,like_la cervecerÃ\xada de barrio"

df["Tags"]=df.Tags.apply(lambda x: x.split(',') x[0].replace('') if x=='importacion' else pass )
```

obviously its not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LRm0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRsQt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to just use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["Tags"] = df["Tags"].str.replace(r'^importacion.*,\s*', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: and if it is not just at the beginning, how would be the regex

Comment: @DiegoGonzálezCastellanos You can try just removing the leading `^` anchor, but we may have to slightly change other parts of the regex as well.  I can't give an exact update without seeing the sample data and how you want the output to be.

Comment: The problem is that in one field it is alone without the coma at the end

Comment: Edit your question, add sample data, and we go can go from there.

Comment: @DiegoGonzálezCastellanos Add ? after ,   `r'^importacion.*,?\s*'`